# Three.js: How to add maps to an OBJ object to get a photorealistic metallic material?

Tags: javascript, three.js

For a little project, I would like to add different maps to an OBJ object in a Three.js 3D scene to get a photorealistic metallic effect. Unfortunately, I have some problems with it.

Directly embedding the code here in a working way doesn't work. So I created this as template:
https://codepen.io/Anna_B/pen/NWroEMP

The material should look like [here](https://threejs.org/docs/scenes/material-browser.html#MeshStandardMaterial), if you add under `THREE.MeshStandardMaterial` the `envMaps`, `map`, and `roughnessMap`.

I have tried to write it like this:

```js
import * as THREE from "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js";

import {
  OBJLoader
} from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js";

var container;

var camera, scene, renderer;

var mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0;

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


const textureLoader = new TextureLoader();

const envMaps = (function() {

  const path = '../../examples/textures/cube/SwedishRoyalCastle/';
  const format = '.jpg';
  const urls = [
    path + 'px' + format, path + 'nx' + format,
    path + 'py' + format, path + 'ny' + format,
    path + 'pz' + format, path + 'nz' + format
  ];

  const reflectionCube = cubeTextureLoader.load(urls);
  reflectionCube.format = RGBFormat;

  const refractionCube = cubeTextureLoader.load(urls);
  refractionCube.mapping = CubeRefractionMapping;
  refractionCube.format = RGBFormat;

  return {
    none: null,
    reflection: reflectionCube,
    refraction: refractionCube
  };

})();


const roughnessMaps = (function() {

  const bricks = textureLoader.load('../../examples/textures/brick_roughness.jpg');
  bricks.wrapT = RepeatWrapping;
  bricks.wrapS = RepeatWrapping;
  bricks.repeat.set(9, 1);

  return {
    none: null,
    bricks: bricks
  };

})();


var object;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  container = document.createElement("div");
  container.className = "object";
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    45,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    1,
    2000
  );
  camera.position.z = 250;

  // scene

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xcccccc, 0.4);
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 2);
  pointLight.position.set(100, 100, 50);

  camera.add(pointLight);
  scene.add(camera);

  // manager

  function loadModel() {
    object.traverse(function(child) {
      //This allow us to check if the children is an instance of the Mesh constructor
      if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        child.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
          color: "#555",
          roughness: 0.1,
          metalness: 0.4,
          texture: textureLoader,
          envMap: envMaps,
          roughnessMaps: roughnessMap

        });
        child.material.flatShading = false;

        //Sometimes there are some vertex normals missing in the .obj files, ThreeJs will compute them
      }
    });
    object.position.y = -90;
    scene.add(object);
  }

  var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager(loadModel);

  manager.onProgress = function(item, loaded, total) {
    console.log(item, loaded, total);
  };

  // model

  function onProgress(xhr) {
    if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
      var percentComplete = (xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100;
      console.log("model " + Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + "% downloaded");
    }
  }

  function onError() {}

  var loader = new OBJLoader(manager);

  loader.load(
    "https://threejs.org/examples/models/obj/female02/female02.obj",
    function(obj) {
      object = obj;
    },
    onProgress,
    onError
  );

  //

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", onDocumentMouseMove, false);

  //

  window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize() {
  windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
  mouseX = (event.clientX - windowHalfX) / 2;
  mouseY = (event.clientY - windowHalfY) / 2;
}

//

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * 0.05;
  camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * 0.05;

  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

I think something is completely wrong. It would be sooooo nice if somebody could help me! I would be so thankful!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a ThreeJS tool to experiment with metallic effects, try...

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_displacementmap.html

...which includes a set of controls to easily adjust critical mesh material parameters, and immediately see the affects.  After using this tool, in your specific example, I came up with the following parameters for your mesh material, giving the object a very photo realistic metallic effect, and changing the color of the object to "#88f" for a bluish tint...

```
THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: "#88f",
    metalness: 1,
    roughness: 0.37,
    aoMapIntensity: 1.0,
    ambientIntensity: 0.42,
    envMapIntensity: 2.2,
    displacementScale: 2.1,
    normalScale: 1
});
```

Obviously you'll have to experiment with the aforementioned tool to obtain the specific metallic effect you desire.  Hopefully this assists your efforts...

**EDIT** The environment map feature depends on environment images that are eventually reflected or refracted onto the object.  The codepen example appears to be missing this critical element (ie, the `THREE.CubeTextureLoader()`).  Based on the code in the question, it appears that it was originally adapted from https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap, which I believe has the necessary elements of the desired environment map concept.  Using that ThreeJS example as a baseline, and injecting the `female02.obj` model into the scene, we arrive at...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Adapted from "three.js webgl - materials - cube reflection / refraction [Walt]"</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container"></div>
        <div id="info">
            <a href="https://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> - Adapted from "cube mapping demo."<br />
            Texture by <a href="http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=Textures" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Humus</a>
        </div>

        <script type="module">

            import * as THREE from 'https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js';

            import { OrbitControls } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
            import { OBJLoader } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';

            let container;

            let camera, scene, renderer;

            let pointLight;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000 );
                camera.position.z = 2000;

                //cubemap
                const path = 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/cube/SwedishRoyalCastle/';
                const format = '.jpg';
                const urls = [
                    path + 'px' + format, path + 'nx' + format,
                    path + 'py' + format, path + 'ny' + format,
                    path + 'pz' + format, path + 'nz' + format
                ];

                const reflectionCube = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load( urls );
                const refractionCube = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load( urls );
                refractionCube.mapping = THREE.CubeRefractionMapping;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = reflectionCube;

                //lights
                const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
                scene.add( ambient );

                pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 2 );
                scene.add( pointLight );

                //materials
                const cubeMaterial3 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xff6600, envMap: reflectionCube, combine: THREE.MixOperation, reflectivity: 0.3 } );
                const cubeMaterial2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffee00, envMap: refractionCube, refractionRatio: 0.95 } );
                const cubeMaterial1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, envMap: reflectionCube } );

                //models
                const objLoader = new OBJLoader();

                objLoader.setPath( 'https://threejs.org/examples/models/obj/female02/' );
                objLoader.load( 'female02.obj', function ( object ) {
        
            object.scale.multiplyScalar( 10 );
            object.position.y = - 1200;
            object.children.forEach( mesh => { mesh.material = cubeMaterial1 } );
            scene.add( object );
          
            let object2 = object.clone();
            object2.position.x = -900;
            object2.children.forEach( mesh => { mesh.material = cubeMaterial2 } );
            scene.add( object2 );
            
            let object3 = object.clone();
            object3.position.x = +900;
            object3.children.forEach( mesh => { mesh.material = cubeMaterial3 } );
            scene.add( object3 );
            
                } );

                //renderer
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                //controls
                const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.enableZoom = false;
                controls.enablePan = false;
                controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI / 4;
                controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 1.5;

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();

            }

            function render() {

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Note that the `female02.obj` is composed of over a dozen meshes, so the object has to be `cloned()` and then the mesh material set for each of the individual meshes.

Comment: Hey, thank you! Look pretty good. Butt still envMaps would be veeeery nice. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @Anna_B the answer has been edited to include environment maps, simply by leveraging the appropriate ThreeJS example.